# Apache Commons FTP Library - listFiles function exception

Tags: java

I've been dealing with Apache Commons FTP Library since last week and this is one hell of a torment. I am not able to connect to any online FTP but it may be a fault of router settings to which I have no access. Anyhow, I used IIS in order to create local FTP on my hard drive. Finally I managed to connect with this FTP.

Cool. This FTP also works on internet explorer.

ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory() function works fine as well, returning string "/"

BUT there is a crush with listFiles function (the second method is in separate thread that invokes the first method):

```
    public static void ftpPrintFilesList(String dir_path) {
    try {
        Log.e(TAG, "1");
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles(dir_path);
        int length = ftpFiles.length;
        Log.e(TAG, "2, length: " + length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
            boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();
            Log.e(TAG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+ name);
            if (isFile) {
                Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "3 ????"+ name);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "4 ####");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public void run(){
     if(FTP.ftpConnect(host, user, password, 21))
        {
            DotNetWSActivity.rslt="connected";
        }
        else
        {
            DotNetWSActivity.rslt="disconnected";
        } 
        //DotNetWSActivity.rslt2 = "cookie monster";
        FTP.ftpPrintFilesList(FTP.ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory());
        Boolean status1 = FTP.ftpDownload("test.txt", "/storage/sdcard");       
}
```

Log shows that listFiles generates an exception that is catched.
I tried to pass "/" instead of FTP.ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory() but there is no difference. Tried .toString() still nothing.
My local ftp is not empty, there are several files and they are visible from the explorer.
'FTP' is a correct object, because I can successfuly connect to my FTP.

Do you have any idea what is wrong in my approach/usage of this library? 
 I will consider using this: 
 
http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpj/overview.html
if there is no answer to my problem.

/////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////
I attach the mentioned log below: 
/////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////

```
10-17 09:51:05.312: I/Choreographer(967): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

10-17 09:51:33.881: D/gralloc_goldfish(1015): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

10-17 09:52:00.761: I/Choreographer(1015): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

**10-17 09:52:52.111: E/(1015): 1**

**10-17 09:52:52.654: E/(1015): 4 ####**

10-17 09:52:52.661: W/System.err(1015): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 49867): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

10-17 09:52:52.692: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)

10-17 09:52:52.692: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)

10-17 09:52:52.701: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)

10-17 09:52:52.701: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)

10-17 09:52:52.711: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)

10-17 09:52:52.711: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)

10-17 09:52:52.711: W/System.err(1015):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)

10-17 09:52:52.711: W/System.err(1015):     at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactory.java:40)

10-17 09:52:52.721: W/System.err(1015):     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:502)

10-17 09:52:52.721: W/System.err(1015):     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2296)

10-17 09:52:52.731: W/System.err(1015):     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2269)

10-17 09:52:52.731: W/System.err(1015):     at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2046)

10-17 09:52:52.731: W/System.err(1015):     at com.prgguru.android.FTP.ftpPrintFilesList(FTP.java:81)

10-17 09:52:52.741: W/System.err(1015):     at com.prgguru.android.Caller5.run(Caller5.java:25)

10-17 09:52:52.751: W/System.err(1015): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

10-17 09:52:52.801: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)

10-17 09:52:52.801: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)

10-17 09:52:52.811: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)

10-17 09:52:52.831: W/System.err(1015):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)

10-17 09:52:52.863: W/System.err(1015):     ... 13 more

10-17 09:52:52.891: D/(1015): download failed
```

When I connect to the FTP there is already a line with mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

```
public static boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,
        String password, int port) {
    try {
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();

        mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            mFTPClient.setFileTransferMode(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            return status;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the FTP server is trying to connect back to you. You should look for "passive" FTP in your API.

Comment: should be mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

Comment: nope it is not; in my 'connect' function there is already such a line